# Case-Insensitive match with SQL/shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "enter user ID\n"

read user_ID

echo "Searching user id $user_ID"

variable1=`sqlplus -s /  <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF ESCAPE '\'
select hr_id from users where hr_id LIKE '%\$user_ID %';
EXIT;
EOF`

if [ -n "$variable1" ];
then
echo "deleting the id $variable1"

variable2=`sqlplus -s /  <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF ESCAPE '\'
delete from users where hr_id= '$user_ID';

else
echo "Please enter correct user ID."
fi
```

I need sql query to search correct user id from db even if its given in any format

```
select hr_id from users where hr_id LIKE '%\$user_ID %';
```

I want to delete user id `ab123c`. If user provides `aBc123C` with any case format it should search and find `ab123c` itself from db, as the id provided will be unique.

the user ID can be AB12C , ab12c or 'ab12c ' any of them not sure. only the known thing is the alphabet and number provided in id will be in same sequence as provided and would be unique.

Comment: Convert the input to lowercase, then use `WHERE LOWER(hr_id) LIKE`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It may have a built-in way to do case-insensitive matching.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, just cast them both to lower case if you are sure the names are unique:

```
select hr_id from users where LOWER(hr_id) LIKE LOWER('%\$user_ID%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
SELECT hr_id FROM users WHERE hr_id LIKE '%\$user_ID %' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT hr_id FROM users WHERE LOWER(hr_id) LIKE LOWER('%\$user_ID %');
```

If you're using PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT hr_id FROM users WHERE hr_id ILIKE '%\$user_ID %';
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell your shell user_ID is lowercase:

```
typeset -l user_ID
read user_ID
echo ${user_ID}
```

Comment: the user ID can be AB12C , ab12c or 'ab12c ' any of them not sure. only the known thing is the alphabet and number provided in id will be in same sequence as provided and would be unique.

Comment: Yep. `typeset -l userID; userID=abCD12EF; echo $userID` returns `abcd12ef`